# scikit learn error - 100. * self.contamination) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'type'

Tags: scikit-learn, isolation

I am trying to build an isolation forest for a csv file I have predicting 'pages' from various size values. The 'pages' value are currently 'low' and 'high' and I have encoded them to be 0 and 1 so that I can detect anomalies. However, I keep getting the error '  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_iforest.py", line 312, in fit
    100. * self.contamination)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'type''

I have attached the code below, thank you so much for your help!

```
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
integer_encoded=label_encoder.fit_transform(values)
print(integer_encoded)
print(len(integer_encoded))
df['pages']= integer_encoded
X = df.iloc[:, 0:101].values
y = df['pages']
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
model = IsolationForest(n_estimators = 50, max_samples = 'auto', contamination = float)
model.fit(df[['pages']])
```

Comment: which line is 312?

Comment: self.contamination needs to be a `float`, what is it? where are you defining it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So SciKit is open-source, you can see the file you need here:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/8feb04524caf78c6a84b56fc59917a0eadcb69c2/sklearn/ensemble/_iforest.py

`_iforest.py`

The line in question is line 283 on latest as of June 11th 2020

You can then look above at the `init` of this file and see that `contamination` is an argument in the constructor.  If you don't pass it, it uses `auto` which defaults the value to `0.5`

You need to make sure you pass a float as the `contamination` value when you initialize the forest

EDIT: note that you don't need to pass anything into the constructor/initialization for `contamination` because it has that default value